# Are the horizontal and vertical subbundle preserved under isometry?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology, tangent-bundle

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and $TM$ its tangent bundle, equipped with the Sasaki metric $g_S$. Let $T_1M$ be the unit tangent bundle (consisting of all tangent vectors of unit length), with metric given by restriction of $g_S$.

My question is: Does an isometry of $T_1M$ preserve its $S^1$-fibre structure? Or, phrased differently: Are the vertical and horizontal subbundle of $TT_1M$ (or even $TTM$) preserved under the differential of such an isometry? If so, is there any easy argument to show this? Or some reference?

Maybe some context: I am currently studying Thurston's eight geometries, in particular the Seifert fibred ones. One of them, the space $\widetilde{\mathrm{SL}}_2(\mathbb{R})$ can be seen as the universal cover of $\mathrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ (the projective linear group), which is isomorphic to the orientation preserving isometry group of $\mathbb{H}^2$. Since this groups acts transitively on $T_1\mathbb{H^2}$ with trivial stabilizers, it can be identified with $T_1\mathbb{H}^2$. Then, we take the Sasaki metric on $T_1\mathbb{H}^2$ and pull it back to get a metric on $\widetilde{\mathrm{SL}}_2(\mathbb{R})$. Note that $\widetilde{\mathrm{SL}}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is fibred by lines (the preimages of the $S^1$-fibres of $T_1\mathbb{H}^2$). On important feature is that every closed 3-manifold $M$ modelled on $\widetilde{\mathrm{SL}}_2(\mathbb{R})$ (that is, $M$ is a quotient $\widetilde{\mathrm{SL}}_2(\mathbb{R})/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a discrete subgroup of $\mathrm{Isom}(\mathbb{H}^2)$ acting freely and properly discontinuously on $\widetilde{\mathrm{SL}}_2(\mathbb{R})$) is Seifert fibred. The argument involves that any isometry of $\widetilde{\mathrm{SL}}_2(\mathbb{R})$ leaves its line fibration invariant. This should be the same as saying that any isometry of $T_1\mathbb{H}^2$ leaves its $S^1$-fibration invariant (which, on a tangent level, corresponds to the vertical subbundle). See also [Scott (1983)](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/%7Emasgar/Teach/2021_3MFDS/References/1983the_geometries_of_three-manifolds.pdf)

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: (1) Presumably you mean $S^{n-1}$-fibre not $S^1$-fibre, since you haven't impose condition on $\dim M=2$.  (2) No, the isometries of $SO(3)$ in $T_1\mathbb{S}^2\cong (SO(3), K=\frac14)$ has no reason to preserve the $S^1$-fibres of $SO(3)\to S^2$. (3) A simple calculation of the (Ricci/sectional) curvature shows the $S^1$-fibres of $T_1\mathbb{H}^2$ are indeed preserved.

Comment: As an even more trivial counterexample, consider the isometries of $T_1\mathbb{R}\cong\mathbb{R}\sqcup\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Kajelad That is not a counterexample to the question in the middle of the second paragraph (and also the title), for example.

Comment: @user10354138 Thank you, you are right of course. I will try doing the computations for $T_1\mathbb{H}^2$.

Comment: What you should discover is that the $S^1$-fibre direction is, for example, the only positive eigenspace for the Ricci (and the orthogonal $\mathbb{H}^2$ (lift) directions the negative eigenspace) or in terms of sectional curvature, you get $\frac14K^2=\frac14$ for any tangent 2-plane containing the $S^1$-direction and $K(1-\frac34K)=-\frac74$ on orthogonal $\mathbb{H}^2$-lift.